# Regex for date in other string

Tags: java, regex

This is my example string:

```
xzyxxy%MM%xyzxy%DD%xyyzy
```

I want to turn this into a regular expression. MM has to be in range 1-12 and DD in the range 1-31. Here are possible strings that matches the regex:

```
xzyxxy5xyzxy28xyyzy
xzyxxy11xyzxy2xyyzy
xzyxxy12xyzxy31xyyzy
```

I'm very new to regular expression and my first idea was to get a regex for MM and DD and than append it with the other string. This could be my java method:

```
String getRegex()   { 
    String MMRegex = "";
    String DDRegex = "";

    String regex;
    regex = expression.replaceAll("%DD%", DDRegex);
    regex = regex.replaceAll("%MM%", MMRegex);

    return regex; 
}
```

The problem is when i find a regex for DD and MM and append it with the other string it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "append it with the other string?"

Comment: Something like in this example:

       A[0-9]B

Here I must type a number between 0 and 9 between the literals A and B
Here i'm Appendig the regex between these two strings

Comment: also what's with the xyxyxyzyz - how do you know you've hit a year/month/day...?

Comment: You don't need to use regex to replace the literal strings "%MM%" and "%DD%"

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Are you sure the problem isn't with the regexes? What do they look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe what you want doesn't have anything to do with regular expressions. If you want to past day and month in a string, you could use:

```
String answer = String.format("xzyxxy%dxyzxy%dxyyzy", 5, 28);
```

The again, if you are looking to go the other way, maybe use:

```
String date = "xzyxxy5xyzxy28xyyzy";
String dateparts[] = x.split("[^0-9]+");
```

then dateparts[1] would be "5" and dateparts[2] would be "28"
is that something you could use?